# Haskell: Check if Int is in a list of Int's

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, sorry if this is a basic question.

I currently have a list of Int's and I am trying to create a function that takes a variable x and returns a boolean depending whether the variable exists in the list.

I have had a search and found Data.List find function but this dosent seem to return a boolean.

I am using GHCi.

Thanks,

Answer (score 104, accepted):

First find the type of the function you need.

To "Check if" means to return either True or False, a Bool.

So the function takes an Int, a list of Int (aka [Int]) and returns Bool:

```
Int -> [Int] -> Bool
```

Now [ask hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+[Int]+-%3E+Bool).

```
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

Hoogle is a very useful tool. You can [integrate it with ghci](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hoogle#GHCi_Integration).

Comment: Asking google lead me here. You don't have to be harsh to OP.

Comment: How can I improve the tone of the answer? I was not trying to be harsh.

Comment: Summarizing  you can use `elem 1 [5, 2, 1, 8]` or the infix way `1 \`elem\` [5, 2, 1, 8]`, in both cases it will returns `True` because 1 is in the list. Of course you can use variables instead

Comment: very useful trick searching by type to find function. in OOP languages, one can use .(dot) to find all the "methods", whereas in Haskell, one can search for functions this way. quite interesting.

Comment: Hoogle is a great tool, thanks for this!  I think I learned about it years ago before I really understood the functional design pattern and didn't appreciate how useful it'd be.

Answer (score 20):

If the standard `elem` function didn't exist, you could have been on the right track with `find`.

```
myElem :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
myElem x = maybe False (const True) . find (== x)
```

There's lots of other ways to implement it too, like

```
myElem x = any (== x)
myElem x = or . map (== x)
myElem x = not . null . filter (== x)
myElem x = foldr (\y b -> y == x || b) False
```

etc.

Answer (score 9):

I'm in my 2 months of trying to learn Haskell during my spare time. Professionally, I do C/C++ for several years. I must say, that the first month of learning Haskell was a headspin experience. I always try to do things on my own if the problem is simple enough rather than using existing APIs like `elem`. I'm slowly learning the FP way, and below is my solution:

```
isMember n [] = False
isMember n (x:xs)
    | n == x = True
    | otherwise = isMember n xs
```

Usage:

```
isMember 2 [1,9,4,5] -- False
isMember 2 [4,5,2,9] -- True
```

Answer (score -1):

i did it more simply like this.

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5]


checkIfElem :: Int -> [Int] ->Bool
checkIfElem x l 
         |x`elem` l =True
         |otherwise=False
```

Comment: That is indeed simple, but one could also say it's an incredibly complicated way of writing the definition `checkIfElem = elem`, because it's _exactly_ equivalent to that!       (Guards already check on boolean values, `| condition = True` `| otherwise = False` therefore is equivalent to simply `= condition`. That leaves you with `checkIfElem x l = elem x l`, where by η-reduction you can drop the arguments on both sides.)

Comment: I don't think this is simple.